# Правильная работа с большим количеством сокетов Python AsyncIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, asyncio

Необходимо по циклу без остановки создавать сотни тысяч сокетов и отправлять данные, почитал что для этого лучше использовать asyncio.

Набросал вариант по типу такого, но уверен, что можно лучше. Что подскажите?

```
import asyncio, concurrent.futures, socks

async def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4500) as executor:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = [
            loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                connect
            )
            for i in range(10000000)
        ]
        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            pass

def connect():
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    try:
        sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9000))
        sock.sendall('some data')
    except Exception as err:
         print("Error: " + str(err))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Вы в этом коде не используете asyicio. Вы просто зачем-то запускаете потоки через asyncio - абсолютно бессмысленное занятие. В документнции asyncio рассказывается, как правильно работать с сокетами

Comment: начните с более простой задачи: сделайте *два* (всего два) *одновременных* запроса средствами asyncio, то есть *не используя дополнительных потоков.*

Comment: А ещё можно флудить в равке. Когда ответ не нужен это лучший вариант, не требуется установка соединений и оверхед на создание сокета никакой.